# CKEDITOR 4.0 Toolbar does not load all given items

Tags: ckeditor, toolbar

I'm now struggling a few hours with the toolbar.
I use this config:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // config.toolbar  = 'Full';
    config.language = 'nl';

    config.enterMode      = 'CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR';
    config.shiftEnterMode = 'CKEDITOR.ENTER_DIV';

    config.contentsCss = [
        '/bundles/mvcms/admin/css/bootstrap.css'
    ];

    // Remove plugin.
    config.removePlugins = 'elementspath';

    config.toolbar = [
        [ 'Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic' ]
    ];
};
```

He shows the bold and Italic, but the Source is hidden...
If I implement the Full toolbar also items are hidden?
I's sure that the ckeditor uses that config file, if I switch bold and italic it does also in de ckeditor.

What is wrong?

- Version: 4.0.0
- replace by class `ckeditor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you've downloaded the **basic package** which does not include **sourcearea** plugin. Download standard or full package or add sourcearea plugin to your package built by the [online builder](http://ckeditor.com/builder).